# How can I pass environment variables by using dotenv in react app ? I get undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dotenv

This is my react fontend app. to pass data from node.js backend, I need to successfully pass API's url.  currently im setting the address to my localhost.

I am struggling to path process.env.API_URL to my config file.

my files structure is

```
.src
  - config
    * config.js
  - .env
.webpack.config.js
```

my .env file is

```
API_URL=http://localhost:3006
```

my config file is below but im getting "undefined" as my console result here.  clearly variable is not passing successfully.

```
console.log(process.env.API_URL)

const config = {
  host: process.env.API_URL
};

export default config;
```

I have installed both "npm install dotenv --save" and "npm i dotenv-webpack"

Inside my Webpack.config.js is below.  I feel like I am just so close to be working but I just cannot figure it out what's the problem here.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' }); 


module.exports = {
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
    }),
  ],
};
```

any suggestions is appreciated.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have .env in src folder and you are trying to access it on same level as webpackConfig. So move the `.env` file on the same level as config or fix your import.

Comment: Ah it is that simple! it worked! thank you